# openjdk 7 java freeze launch

Tags: java, 15.10, openjdk, jdk, oracle

### ***NOTE: Found a workaround, I just want to know where the problem is.***

Hello everyone,

I am attempting to run a java *.jar file that runs on my debian setup but cannot get to run on a fresh install of Ubuntu with openjdk-7.

Setup
Ubuntu 15.10, fresh 64-bit 
installed default-jdk
downloaded XMage.jar from xmage.de.

Using the terminal -verbose option I notice that it freezes at the following line:

```
[loading sun.awt.X11.XKeysym$Keysym2JavaKeycode from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

After 5 minutes I killed it. I then removed default-jdk and installed Oracle Java, which was able to run the jar file.

I am unsure if the issue lies with me, the version of Java, or the jar file. Any ideas on how I can find out more information? Never debugged java before.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  It's possible to [edit] your question yourself to correct it, by clicking on the [edit] link between your question and these comments.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like it was a problem with OpenJDK. `rt.jar` is the Java Runtime and contains all the code needed to spin up a new JVM and run your app on it. It's hanging when loading a [static class](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/awt/X11/XKeysym$Keysym2JavaKeycode.html) related to X11, which handles graphics. You can also tell this because it's part of the `AWT` API, which is part of the Java SE graphics libraries.

To properly debug this, you could create a Java core dump, or use a JDK tool like `jstack` to dump out all the threads. These aren't trivial to search through if you're unfamiliar with the topic, though, so you might not want to go into that much depth.

Comment: Thanks, im not against going down the rabbit hole but was not sure where to start. This helps!

Comment: No problem, comment again here if you need any more guidance and I'll expand the answer. It's probably useful to others as well.